# Self tan mousse cannot contain UV, right?

Tags: fluorescence

So, I bought this self tanner specificly to avoid UV radiation. Back home I noticed that the bottle says it contains ultra violet: "The inclusion of Ultra Violet fluorescence in the base colour" . I guess they meant it contains something fluorescent but what could it be and is it dangerous? (sorry about my bad English)

The product is Sunkissed Ultra Dark Selfie Ready Tan.

Answer (score 1):

That's right, it can't contain UV, because UV light is not a thing you can put in a bottle. The rest I'd rather dismiss as some marketing gibberish akin to this:

[image: Tho-Radia]

(sold back in the days when radium was all the hype, this thing is probably less awful than it seems, because it could not realistically have contained more than a few atoms of radium.)

---

Then again, chances are that the gibberish bears some resemblance to actual facts; so what? Fluorescence is just the ability to absorb and re-emit light. Whatever its composition may be, this thing would not shine UV on you all by itself.

As to the possible dangers, you either trust the regulatory body acting in your jurisdiction, or you don't. At least these guys supposedly did test the product, which I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I looked for the whole product description and it is highly misleading. 
It also states:

> ...and the inclusion of Ultra Violet works by reducing the bounce back of the camera lights so that your tan looks darker in the photos.

Either there is a chemical in there that's called "Ultra Violet" or it just makes no sense. I suppose the latter. UV is a radiation that cannot be "stored" and even if it would never reduce the reflecion or "bounce back" of light.

For the facts:

Flourescense would mean that there is a chemical in the tanner that absorbs light and radiates it again (just like the self glowing clock faces on watches). This would mean that you would glow in the darkness with this stuff. But this effect would not protect you from UV radiation and you can certainly not "store" it.

In general self tanners are glorified coloring agents in a fatty matrix, in the best case with a sun protection agent. The product description is utter nonsense. Whoever made it has not even a tiny bit of chemical knowledge.

For the product: I can't say if it's dangerous. I would use a different product just because of the misleading description and use a tanner from a local drug store.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this very much sounds like it was written by someone who doesn't know what UV or fluorescence means.
I contacted the company via their website and asked for clarification:

> Dear Sunkissed,
>   I read about your product, "Sunkissed Ultra Dark Selfie Ready Tan," and I read that it "contains Ultra Violet fluorescence in the base colour." A customer of yours was worried that UV might be dangerous. I am a chemistry teacher, and I could assure them that there was no "UV" in the cream. I am very curious what it is that your cream contains though. You say,
>   "The inclusion of Ultra Violet fluorescence in the base colour helps to intensify your colour under camera lights," and "the inclusion of Ultra Violet works by reducing the bounce back of the camera lights so your tan appears darker in photos." I am finding that hard to parse. If there is a fluorescent dye in the cream, the person using it should appear *brighter* in UV light (like a disco, or sunlight), but camera lights don't contain much UV. "Reducing the bounce back of the camera lights" sounds like the cream absorbs visible light, i.e. it isn't white or transparent, but that has nothing to do with fluorescence.
>   I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide further information on what it is that this cream contains and how it is meant to work.
>   Thank you, and have a great day,
>   Martin

I'll let you know if I get a response.

Feel free to not buy this stuff again, and to leave a comment with the company or with the person hawking this cream on Youtube. Trying to make money by confusing people with $20 words is wrong.

Also: if your goal is to "avoid UV radiation," the product you want to get is sunscreen. (Or an umbrella, or a hat, or a shirt.)

Comment: No response from Sunkissed.